# Select 3 by 3 sql

Tags: sql, select

How to design a query that selects only id's that divide 3 (id%3=0). How to create this rule in query?

For example:

```
1 A
2 B 
3 C
4 D 
5 E
6 F 
7 G
```

This query should only return
3 and 6 (C and F).

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Then post that code as well. Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for **MSSQL**

```
select * from table where table_id % 3 = 0
```

for **Oracle SQL**

```
select * from table where mod(table_id,3) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler example for MySQL (and most databases):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` % 3 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL Database, according to the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) you can do this :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MOD(`table`.`id`, 3) = 0
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`table`.`id` % 3) = 0
```

Comment: I don't put -1 for you , But i know your 1st post is wrong (Now you edited) , That time anyone put -1 for you !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 SELECT * FROM yourtable where ID % 3 =0
```